# Long number prime detection using Multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, c99

Problem Statement: To detect whether a long integer number is a prime or not. 
My Logic: 
The idea is to iterate from 0 to sqrt(n). If no divisor was found between 0 to sqrt(n) then I can conclude that the number is prime and a non-prime otherwise. 
Since, this needs to be multi-threaded I created a thread function called `void* PrimeDetecter(void* param);`. In this thread function I will iterate from `startIndex` to `endIndex` and if there was a divisor then quit the thread and write the value 1 to state true to the address of the variable `isNum1Prime` which is set to 0 by default. 
Therefore, in the main function I need to send the number which will be checked, its start index and end index to the thread when creating the thread. So my structure will contain `long int number, startIndex, endIndex, *divisor` and `int isPrime`. 
Then I create an array of size 10 of type NumberPrime because there are 10 threads and hence divide the iteration equally.
I printed the distribution of index among the threads and that works fine. Then I just create the threads and send all these elements to the thread to check whether the number is prime or not.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_NUM_THREADS 10 // Exercise 1: Not more than 10 threads can run at a time for example.

struct NumberPrime
{
    long int number, startIndex, endIndex, *divisor;
    int *isPrime;
};

void *PrimeDetector(void *param)
{
    struct NumberPrime parameters = *(struct NumberPrime *)param;
    for (long int i = parameters.startIndex; i < parameters.endIndex; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((parameters.number % i) == 0) // if the divisor is detected then number is not a prime
            {
                *(parameters.divisor) = i;
                *(parameters.isPrime) = 1; // change the value to true
                pthread_exit(0);          // exit the thread function
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long int number1 = 12340000, number2 = 128;
    struct NumberPrime primeData1[MAX_NUM_THREADS];
    int isNum1Prime = 0; // false
    long int number1Divisor = 0;
    long int numberSquareRoot1 = (long int)(sqrt(number1)); // get the square root of number1

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        primeData1[i].number = number1;
        primeData1[i].isPrime = &isNum1Prime;
        primeData1[i].divisor = &number1Divisor;
        primeData1[i].startIndex = i * numberSquareRoot1 / MAX_NUM_THREADS;
        primeData1[i].endIndex = ((i + 1) * numberSquareRoot1) / MAX_NUM_THREADS;
    }

    pthread_t primeDetectorThread1[MAX_NUM_THREADS];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        if (isNum1Prime == 1)
        {
            pthread_cancel(primeDetectorThread1[i]);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_create(&primeDetectorThread1[i], NULL, &PrimeDetector, &primeData1[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(primeDetectorThread1[i], NULL);
    }

    isNum1Prime == 1 ? printf("Number 1 is prime.\n") : printf("Number 1 is not prime and divisible by %ld\n", number1Divisor);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The expected output is that the number is not a prime. But no matter what number I choose I always get that the number is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if ((parameters.number % i) == 0)` tests whether a number **is** divisible by `i`. If it is divisible, the number is **not** prime, but your code goes on to set `*(parameters.isPrime) = 1;` and end the thread.

Comment: Hmm ok I changed it. But now I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) error?